# Disable bootstrap.js when run unit tests

Tags: sails.js, mocha.js

I have `sails.on('lifted',...)` in `config\bootstrap.js`.
How to not run this when running `mocha` unit tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While running tests, you can [`load`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/application/sails-load) sails instead of lifting it.

```
var Sails = require('sails').Sails;

before(function (done) {
    new Sails().load(
        {},  // your configuration
        done
    );
});

after(function (done) {
    if (sails) { return sails.lower(done); }
    return done();
});
```